# How to alphabetize a list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, alphabetized

I want to alphabetize a list in prolog so I can then strip the head or tail of that list to deal with -- essentially make it easier to deal with things in alphabetical (or reverse alphabetical) order.  I receive the words in varying order every time (not already alphabetized nor in the same order); eg,

'ra1'
'ra2'
'rb2'
'ra3'
'rb1'

I can't hard code the list; it might be 9, or 16 items, etc., so I want to sort them into a single alphabetized list of 'ra1', 'ra2', 'ra3', 'rb1', 'rb2'...

I should be able to use 'compare'.  E.g.,

```
compare(Res, 'ra2', 'ra1').
Res = (>).
```

This is it for exactly 2 items, and now I need it for some unspecified number of items.  Ideas?

```
places(['zzz', 'aaa']).

alph(Outlist, Inlist) :- 
    member(A, Inlist),
    member(B, Inlist),
    compare(<, A, B),
    A \= B,
    % and they go in that order in a new list.
    append([A], [B], Outlist).
```

Comment: Do you mean sorting the list? `sort/2` is a standard predicate (which removes duplicates, which may or may not be a problem in your case). Some Prolog implementations also provide sorting predicates that keep duplicates and sorting predicates where you can specify your own sorting criteria.

Comment: Have you made any attempts at a solution?

Comment: Yes, it will be sorting, but I don't understand how to use that predicate.  Looking at that brings me to 'compare' though, which is probably good enough since I can do this (don't know how to get in line breaks..): <entering> compare(A, 'box', 'xob'). <returns>
A = (<).
<entering>
compare(A, 'xob', 'box').
<returns> A = (>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using standard `sort/2` predicate is easy:

```
?- sort(['ra1', 'ra2', 'rb2', 'ra3', 'rb1'], Sorted).
Sorted = [ra1, ra2, ra3, rb1, rb2].
```

If your list can have duplicates, change `sort` to `msort`, because `sort/2` eliminates duplicates.